# Get value of textarea fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I'm having a for with a textarea and I want to use `jQuery` to get the content of a text area. Therefore I've written following coffeescript function

```
submitPost: (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    form = $('.js-new-post-form')
    field = form.find(".js-post-text")
    alert(field.val())
```

This successfully finds the textarea. Evaluating `field` in the js console returns

```
<textarea class=​"js-post-text" id=​"post_text" name=​"post[post]​">​</textarea>​
```

However, `field.val()` always returns `""`, although there is content in the textarea. What's the error in my code?

Comment: Does your form actually have the class `js-new-post-form`?

Comment: Ses it has. Since `form.find()` works correctly, I assume finding the form was successful.

Comment: Can you post the HTML of the form here?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just get the value like this?

```
$("#post_text").val();
```

Comment: This works! Thank you. Can you tell my why the original code fails?

Comment: It seems you are using jQuery like plain javaScript. This is the part where it looses the val                                                       form = $('.js-new-post-form')
field = form.find(".js-post-text")

Comment: That's not true @Defain! There's nothing wrong with those two lines; that's proper jQuery.

Comment: If it was correct it would return the value. However I did not say it was not proper jQuery and that is the point where the proper path to textarea value is lost

Answer (score 0):

you can check if the js-post-text if found or not 
Try this

```
 form = $('.js-new-post-form')
field = form.find(".js-post-text")
alert(field.length)
```

if length is available there then

```
field.each(function(){
alert($(this).val());
});
```

it should work..